# Setting up Git and cloning a remote GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

My team lead has set up a remote GitHub repository and i have been sent an invite to that repository. I have to clone it to my local device and i have not yet set up Git on my local device yet

I am confused as to whether i have to use the URL of the Host's GitHub repository or my own GitHub account's URL as I have already been invited and should I clone it from the host or my own GitHub account,I'm an very elementary at all this

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the URL of host's github repo who setup the repo.

Comment: okay i will try that, also regarding SSH key should i add it to my own github account ?

Comment: Yes. That key is for your account.